# Hangfire - Long running jobs repeats after 30mins

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have job that processing some heavy data and it will run more than hour.

Problems is, after 30 mins job starting another worker and failing to finish with exceptions tied to Distributed Lock:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
```

[Processing Jobs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Jz2.png)

I'm using `MySql Storage` with Options from the Hangfire.MySql.Core library with version 2.2.5:

```
new MySqlStorageOptions
  {
    TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
    JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
    DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
    TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    TablesPrefix = ""
   })
```

I read everything that I found online and in documentation, and it says to use it with:

```
InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
```

But that parameter is obsolete now from Hangfire version > 1.5.

[Invisibility Timeout is obsolete](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2015/07/31/hangfire-1.5.0-beta.html#instant-re-queue-for-sql-server)

I'm using Hangfire.Core 1.7.7 and still having this issue after 30mins of running job.

**EDIT**:

Tried with:

```
InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
```

And Job running for an hour without problems.

I don't like obsolete solution, and it will be removed on Hangfire 2.0.

They say:

> "New Hangfire.SqlServer implementation uses plain old transactions to
>   fetch background jobs and hide them from other workers."

-But this is wrote for `SQL Server` implementation, I'm using `MySql Storage`.

Anyone encountered same problem with `MySql Storage`?

Comment: We solved it by migrating Hangfire on MS SQL, and use MariaDB for our DB. And we noticed increased performance on MS SQL when Jobs are changes states. Hangfire fixed issue on MS SQL, but on MySQL problem still persists. 

My advice - if anyone have problem with MYSQL is to migrate Hangfire on MS SQL and keep your MySQL for databases.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, using Mysql.Core 2.2.5, hangfire core 1.7.7. 
If I remembered correctly, this issue doesn't occur when using SQL Server 2017 Express. I used sql server and didn't notice this issue. But after I changed to mysql the issue occurs.
I wonder this is the implementation of Hangfire.MySql.Core 2.2.5. Maybe we can contact the author of this package to get the answer. https://github.com/stulzq/Hangfire.MySql.Core

Comment: Hey, Aaron, we solved it by migrating Hangfire on MS SQL, and use MariaDB for our DB. And we noticed increased performance on MS SQL when Jobs are changes states. 

Hangfire fixed issue on MS SQL, but on MySQL problem still persists. 

My advice is to migrate Hangfire on MS SQL and keep your MYSQL for databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Memory Storage, Then you can use the below configuration.

```
services.AddHangfire(config => {
            config.UseMemoryStorage(new MemoryStorageOptions { FetchNextJobTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) });
        });
```